# magento1.9: Index page showing blank in admin panal

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-panel

Index page showing blank in admin panel.as shown below image:

[image]

No error found anywhere. How can I solve this? Please help.

I have tried this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23285181/magento-index-management-page-just-shows-blank. But no result.

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed or did any customisations to the code lately, which might result in this page being broken? Normally, a screen like this happens when the layout file of an extension (one that does modifications to this page) isn't working correctly or has syntax errors.

Comment: thanks yous suggestion @Arjen. Your idea is correct. There is one custom module causing the issue. I have resolved this.

Comment: I added my comment as an answer. Could you mark that one as a solution for future visitors of this SE question?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any extensions installed or did any customisations to the code lately, which might result in this page being broken?

Normally, a screen like this happens when the layout file of an extension (one that does modifications to this page) isn't working correctly or has syntax errors.